# Cross-validation for low event rate

Tags: cross-validation

I have 1000 observations with 20 events (2%). Splitting them into 10 will get me only 2 events per fold. Splitting the training folds into 10 sub-folds for model building and optimisation will get me even lower event rate.

Question:

1. Is it correct to say that 10-fold cross-validation is not appropriate for these data?
2. What are the alternatives? Is repeating 2-fold validations 1000 times a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it correct to say that 10-fold cross-validation is not appropriate for these data?**

No but you have to tweak the procedure, an example is  <strike>described</strike>  linked below.

**What are the alternatives? Is repeating 2-fold validations 1000 times a better option?**

You can look at `Stratified Cross-validation` [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89768/cross-validation-in-unbalanced-datasets). Since the data is highly unbalanced consider other options such as: SMOTE. But be sure to sample only in training data and not in the test data, i.e., sample within each fold as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60180/testing-classification-on-oversampled-imbalance-data). 
Links below have some good discussion:

a. [Dealing with imbalanced data: undersampling, oversampling and proper cross-validation](http://www.marcoaltini.com/blog/dealing-with-imbalanced-data-undersampling-oversampling-and-proper-cross-validation)

b. [8 Tactics to Combat Imbalanced Classes in Your Machine Learning Dataset](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)